# Weird Python output when printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftdi

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to read pressure data from a Honeywell differential pressure sensor using the LibMPSSE library. I'm reading it from a Adafruit FT232H chip and I'm using python 2.7.6 on ubuntu Linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from mpsse import *

SIZE = 2    # 2 bytes MSB first
WCMD = "\x50"   # Write start address command
RCMD = "\x51"       # Read command
FOUT = "eeprom.txt" # Output file

try:
    eeprom = MPSSE(I2C)

    # print "%s initialized at %dHz (I2C)" % (eeprom.GetDescription(), eeprom.GetClock())

    eeprom.Start()
    eeprom.Write(WCMD)
    # Send Start condition to i2c-slave (Pressure Sensor)
    if eeprom.GetAck() == ACK:
        # ACK received,resend START condition and set R/W bit to 1 for read 
        eeprom.Start()
        eeprom.Write(RCMD)

        if eeprom.GetAck() == ACK:
            # ACK recieved, continue supply the clock to slave
            data = eeprom.Read(SIZE)
            eeprom.SendNacks()
            eeprom.Read(1)
        else:
            raise Exception("Received read command NACK2!")
    else:
        raise Exception("Received write command NACK1!")

    eeprom.Stop()
    print(data)
    eeprom.Close()

except Exception, e:
    print "MPSSE failure:", e
```

According to the library, Read returns a string of size bytes and whenever I want to print the data, the only output I see is �����2��T_`ʋ�Q}�*/�eE�
. I've tried encoding with utf-8 and still no luck.

Comment: I do not have any experience with this library. Try adding `print(type(data))` and `print(','.join(['{:d}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, data)]))` after your last `print(data)` just to see what data is and what it contains.

Comment: @AGNGazer It outputs this: <type 'str'> 6,94. Can you explain me what print(','.join(['{:d}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, data)])) does?

Comment: That long statement is essentially for printing comma-separated ASCII values corresponding to each string character in the `data` string. So, your data string appears to contain only 2 characters... Is this what you would expect?

Comment: If you want to print the content of those two bytes in hex, do this: `print(','.join(['{:02X}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, data)]))`

Comment: @AGNGazer Thanks for the help! Yes, I was expecting to read 2 bytes and those values were the exact values I got when reading the pressure data with a higher level library. I'm wondering if there was a way to combine those 2 data values into a single 2 byte value? Or how would I put the two values into different variables?

Comment: To assign each byte to two variables you could do this: `hi, lo = map(ord, data)` or, if you prefer, replace previous statement with two lines: `hi = ord(data[0])` and `lo = ord(data[1])`. *"I'm wondering if there was a way to combine those 2 data values into a single 2 byte value?"* - What do you mean exactly by that? Do you want an integer that has first two bytes equal to the bytes from data or do you want a string? In the latter case, isn't `data` already what you want - a list of two bytes?

Comment: @AGNGazer Thank you so much for the help. I wanted to know how you knew you had to use ord to extract the values instead of directly printing data[0] and data[1]? What I mean by "I'm wondering if there was a way to combine those 2 data values into a single 2 byte value?" was converting 2 bytes into a single 16 bit number like this num = (hi << 8) | lo.

Comment: You are welcome! It seems you have figured out how to combine the two bytes into a single `int`. With regard to `ord`... My hope was that by printing each byte as an integer (or hex) this will show you that the content of the data string was what you were expecting. When data contain non-printable characters/bytes `print` may represent them in weird ways...

Comment: Let me summarize this in an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Python may print "weird" output when bytes/characters in the string (`data` in your case) contain non-printable characters. To "view" the content of the individual bytes (as integers or hex), do the following:

```
print(','.join(['{:d}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, data)])) # decimal
```

or

```
print(','.join(['{:02X}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, data)]))
```

Since the length of your `data` buffer is set by `SIZE=2`, to extract each byte  from this buffer as an integer you can do the following:

```
hi, lo = map(ord, data)
# or:
hi = ord(data[0])
lo = ord(data[1])
```

To read more about `ord` and what it does - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord